# closed - Caliburn Micro Navigate method doesn't set DataContext of View to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, caliburn.micro

I'm building UWP using Caliburn Micro 3.0.1 and followed [HelloUWP](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloUWP/Caliburn.Micro.HelloUWP) sample.

When I call `_navigationService.For<SomeViewModel>().Navigate()` it doesn't set DataContext of View to ViewModel except ShellViewModel which I think they were bound together in `DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>()` in App.xaml.cs.

It always set View's DataContext to ShellViewModel if `Message.Attach` on `Frame` is set to `cm:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [SetupNavigationService($source)]` and it doesn't set to anything if Frame's DataContext is set to `x:Null`.

Is this normal behavior or a bug?
Does anyone have workaround?

**Update Finally, I solved it.**
At first, I registered ViewModel with container as

```
_container.PerRequest<Screen, SomeViewModel>();
```

later I changed to

```
_container.PerRequest<SomeViewModel>();
```

I've never thought register class as a service with ViewModel as an implementation would cause ViewModelLocator to not found ViewModel for View, which in turn cause ViewModel and View to not bind together.

Comment: did you register `SomeViewModel` with the IoC container?

Comment: @IgorKulman Yes, I did.  it just doesn't set DataContext and Message.Handler to ViewModel.  View itself is show in Frame, no exception was thrown.